# Cannot clear value in text after submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and when I press submit button, all input text should be cleared. The problem is only one input text is actually cleared.

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:panel id="panel" widgetVar="panel">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" Stiky="true" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Nama depan anda : " style="margin-left:550px"/>
            <p:inputText id="v1" value="#{bean.baris.username}" style="margin-left:550px"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Nama belakang anda : " style="margin-left:550px"/>
            <p:inputText id="v2" value="#{bean.baris.belakang}" style="margin-left:550px"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Password anda : " style="margin-left:550px"/>
            <p:password id="v3" value="#{bean.baris.password}" style="margin-left:550px"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                             update="display msgs"
                             actionListener="#{bean.tambah}"
                             style="margin-left:550px">
            </p:commandButton>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
```

Comment: Why would all the input text clear?

Comment: do you want to save the fields and then clear them?

Comment: thanks for comment. i can save input text data to datatable. but cannot clear all input text after i press submit button. only password input can be cleared

Answer (score 0):

On your backing bean method:

```
public void tambah() {
    serviceObject.saveMethod(baris);
    baris.username = "";
    baris.belakang = "";
    baris.password = "";
}
```

As we have called the save method before clearing the form it will satisfy your need, first it will save data in database and then clear the form.

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view transient="true" />
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:panel id="panel" widgetVar="panel">
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" Stiky="true" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Nama depan anda : " style="margin-left:550px" />
                    <p:inputText id="v1"
                        value="#{bean.baris.username}" style="margin-left:550px" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Nama belakang anda : "
                        style="margin-left:550px" />
                    <p:inputText id="v2" value="#{bean.baris.belakang}"
                        style="margin-left:550px" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="Password anda : " style="margin-left:550px" />
                    <p:password id="v3" value="#{bean.baris.password}"
                        style="margin-left:550px" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit"  update="form1"
                        actionListener="#{bean.tambah}"
                        style="margin-left:550px"></p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
</html>
```

Your `tambah` method should like this:

```
public void tambah() {
    username = "";
    belakang = "";
    password = "";
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks for comment. it can cleared all input text. but when i submit into datatable, the records will be empy.